# Activate Child Theme with Codex

Tags: multisite, child-theme

I know there is an option to have the following code in the wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'x-child-integrity-light');
define( 'TEMPLATEPATH', 'wp-content/themes/x');
```

I currently have this commented out and I'm trying to use the WP Replicator to replicate sites in a multisite install. I'd like to have the code automatically activate the child theme when it's installing the new site. By default, it's making the Twenty Fifteen theme active. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `switch_theme` as already indicated in another answer, but hook it to `wpmu_new_blog`

> This function runs when a user self-registers a new site as well as when a super admin creates a new site. hook to 'wpmu_new_blog' for events that should affect all new sites.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/function_reference/wpmu_create_blog

If not the code will run constantly, which will be inefficient and make switching themes impossible ( or unpredictable ).

In other words:

```
function default_theme_wpse_193024() {
  switch_theme('twentythirteen');
}
add_action('wpmu_new_blog','default_theme_wpse_193024');
```

For `switch_theme()`, despite the parameter being named somewhat inexplicably "stylesheet", use the name of the theme folder. [Per the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme):

> Accepts one argument: $stylesheet of the theme. ($stylesheet is the
>   name of your folder slug. It's the same value that you'd use for a
>   child theme, something like `twentythirteen`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `switch_theme` function

```
<?php switch_theme( $stylesheet ) ?>
```

`$stylesheet` is the Stylesheet name.